# Mongoose 4.11.12 pre validate error returns empty JSON response

Tags: mongoose, mongoose-schema

I have that code in Mongoose Model but on Client side, in Ajax Response it returns Empty Error {}

```
tableSchema.pre('validate', function(next) {
 // You **must** do `new Error()`. `next('something went wrong')` will
 // **not** work
 var err = new Error('something went wrong');
 next(err);
});
```

IN CONSOLE IT SHOWS THAT ERROR

```
Error: something went wrong
at model.<anonymous> (/Volumes/D/www/node_js/ck_app_server_client/server/model/AccountModel.js:48:13)
at model._next (/Volumes/D/www/node_js/ck_app_server_client/server/node_modules/hooks-fixed/hooks.js:62:30)
at model.proto.(anonymous function) [as $__original_validate] (/Volumes/D/www/node_js/ck_app_server_client/server/node_modules/hooks-fixed/hooks.js:108:20)
at model.<anonymous> (/Volumes/D/www/node_js/ck_app_server_client/server/node_modules/mongoose/lib/plugins/validateBeforeSave.js:31:14)
at model._next (/Volumes/D/www/node_js/ck_app_server_client/server/node_modules/hooks-fixed/hooks.js:62:30)
at model.proto.(anonymous function) [as $__original_save] (/Volumes/D/www/node_js/ck_app_server_client/server/node_modules/hooks-fixed/hooks.js:108:20)
at /Volumes/D/www/node_js/ck_app_server_client/server/node_modules/mongoose/lib/services/model/applyHooks.js:153:27
at new Promise.ES6 (/Volumes/D/www/node_js/ck_app_server_client/server/node_modules/mongoose/lib/promise.js:45:3)
at model.wrappedPointCut [as save] (/Volumes/D/www/node_js/ck_app_server_client/server/node_modules/mongoose/lib/services/model/applyHooks.js:131:23)
at /Volumes/D/www/node_js/ck_app_server_client/server/routes/accounts.js:36:7
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Volumes/D/www/node_js/ck_app_server_client/server/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
at next (/Volumes/D/www/node_js/ck_app_server_client/server/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)
at Route.dispatch (/Volumes/D/www/node_js/ck_app_server_client/server/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Volumes/D/www/node_js/ck_app_server_client/server/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
at /Volumes/D/www/node_js/ck_app_server_client/server/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:281:22
at Function.process_params (/Volumes/D/www/node_js/ck_app_server_client/server/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
```

Comment: How are you saving and sending the response? Show the rest of your code.

Answer (score 0):

The same behaviour can be demonstrated by this:

```
JSON.stringify(Error('something went wrong'))
```

This results in `{}`, because that's how `Error` instances are serialized to JSON.

If you want to serialize it to something meaningful, you have to make up a structure yourself:

```
JSON.stringify({ error : { message : err.message, stack : err.stack } })
```

There are also [plenty of modules](https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=json%20serialize%20error) that offer something similar.

Comment: You seems to misunderstand my question i meant At client side it returns empty.  
if (err) return res.send(401, { error: err });
err is EMPTY

Comment: @AmanBansal you seem to be misunderstanding my answer: `Error` instances get serialized to an _empty object_ (`{}`) when converted to JSON. That's how it works. You need to work around that by using the specific properties of the `Error` object, which is what my answer is showing.